# Etymology of the name Azriel?

Tags: names, malach-angel, etymology

A quick Google search shows that most people hold this is the angel of death. Where are the sources for this (or any other sources of the name)? If there is a source for this, are people naming their children after it? I know it literally means "help of Hashem" but it still retains the connotation.

Comment: According to Islamic tradition, Azriel is called the angel of death. This is the view of Islam though.

Comment: Well HaRav Shlomo Zalman Auerabach zt"l clearly didn't have an issue with it as he named one of his sons Azriel...

Comment: @Dov as well in Gemara. There are many places where people are called Azriel. As I said above, it seems that it is a Islamic tradition.

Comment: Its in Divrei Hayamim I 5:24 too! - https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.5.24?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en

Comment: You are mixing up Azra'el Azri'el.

Comment: It doesn't mean "help of Hashem" but "Hashem is my help"

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bamidbar.2.2.4?vhe=Midrash_Rabbeinu_Bachya_[ben_Asher]._Warsaw,_1878&lang=bi

Comment: Here is a Zohar tradition of Azriel that is associated with life and death but doesn't seem to quite match the Islamic psychopomp https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Pekudei.48.543?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @RabbiKaii - wrong link - https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Pekudei.48.544?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Dov went back one to help add some context

Comment: @Shmuel interesting, but that being said, what is the actual etymology of the name?

Comment: Also @Shmuel, where is it mentioned in the Gemara?

Comment: * I meant other sources not Gemara per se. [See for example](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Azriel&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance)